# Best way to synch cache

Tags: java, caching, synchronization, hazelcast, consistency

What is the  best practices in order to synch in-memory data grid cache like Hazelcast and database?

Full or incremental?

I read some article and it seems the full synch is most preferred way to synch but they don't mention about that clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Check out https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.11/manual/html-single/index.html#loading-and-storing-persistent-data

You have both options - write-through for syncing on the same write operation initiated for Hazelcast and write-behind to asynchronously write to DB in a batch.

Comment: Thanks @wildnez. But I need to do it from client side. Hazelcast server is commonly used for many other projects.